# Why won't my function execute

Tags: python-2.7

I'm relatively new to python and the only other experience I've had is C++. Whenever I define a function in Python, I can't seem to execute it.
This my current code for my assignment, if possible I just want to know why my code won't execute

```
def birthexp(birthyear):
    product = birthyear**birthyear
    length = len(str(product))
    onesCount = str(product).count("1")
    threeCount = str(product).count("3")
    fiveCount = str(product).count("5")
    sevenCount = str(product).count("7")
    nineCount = str(product).count("9")
    sumCount = onesCount+threeCount+fiveCount+sevenCount+nineCount
    oneRation = onesCount/float(length)*100
    threeRatio = threeCount/float(length)*100
    fiveRatio = fiveCount/float(length)*100
    sevenRatio = sevenCount/float(length)*100
    nineRatio = nineCount/float(length)*100
    totalRatio = sumCount/float(length)*100
    print(str(product) + ": product after multiplying the birth year to itself.")
    print(str(onesCount) + ": number of ones found at a rate of " +str(oneRation)+ "percent.")
    print(str(threeCount) + ": number of threes found at a rate of " +str(threeRatio)+ "percent")
    print(str(fiveCount) + ": number of fives found at a rate of " +str(fiveRatio)+ "percent")
    print(str(sevenCount) + ": number of sevens found at a rate of " +str(sevenRatio)+ "percent")
    print(str(nineCount) + ": number of nine found at a rate of " +str(nineRatio)+ "percent")
    print(str(sumCount) + ": total odd numbers found at a rate of " +str(totalRatio)+ "percent")

birthyear(1990)
```

Comment: is this all of your code in that program?

Comment: Are you calling this function somewhere?

Comment: `totalRatio = sumCount/floar(length)*100`. There is a typo: `floar` should be `float`.

Comment: Functions don't run in python until they are called somewhere such as `birthexp(1990)` will run the code with `birthyear` equal to 1990.

Comment: Even after fixing the typo and calling the function, it still did nothing for me. All it did was indent to the next line instead of calling the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in this line `totalRatio = sumCount/floar(length)*100`. You need `float` instead of `floar`.

Secondly, you have loads of missing parenthesis in almost all lines with the `print` function.

If you want the function to return value, you should use `return` instead of `print`'s:

```
return (str(product)
            + ": product after multiplying the birth year to itself.\n"
            + str(onesCount)
            + ": number of ones found at a rate of " + str(oneRation) + "percent.\n"
            + str(threeCount)
            + ": number of threes found at a rate of " + str(threeRatio) + "percent\n"
            + str(fiveCount)
            + ": number of fives found at a rate of " + str(fiveRatio) + "percent\n"
            + str(sevenCount)
            + ": number of sevens found at a rate of " + str(sevenRatio) + "percent\n"
            + str(nineCount)
            + ": number of nine found at a rate of " + str(nineRatio) + "percent\n"
            + str(sumCount)
            + ": total odd numbers found at a rate of " + str(totalRatio) + "percent\n")
```

Comment: i fixed the missing parenthesis and the float typo. And yet, it still ignores the function. That aside, is the logic in my function even correct?

Comment: After I call the function, it would just go to the next line as if it returned nothing

Comment: @gadde2223 - Well, it doesn't return a thing, it just prints information

Comment: @gadde2223 - It isn't supposed to return anything as there is no `return` statement in the function.

Comment: You pointed out that the output was too large and was a cause for it to not show. Maybe I'm just overthinking it too much. But thanks.

Comment: @gadde2223 - You can check my answer as the right one, then :-)